# WP Add Media Button - Can I set the default size to Original/Full Size

Tags: uploads, media

So when I am adding pictures to a blog post [directly to the 'main content area', below the text], they have the 'Medium' Size.... so I have to go to every single picture and change it to Full Size .... is there a way to set Full Size as default.... so that I just need to hit Add Media and all the pictures would display in Full Size?

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: WordPress should remember the last size you used - just make sure to insert a large media once, and then it should be selected by default for every subsequent item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress will remember the last size you used - just make sure to insert a large media once, and then it will be selected by default for every subsequent item.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default in the database. Go to the options table and look for "image_default_size". As value you put "full" (without ""; or thumbnail, medium or large). As I understand it, it will set the default for every user, not just you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to the options table:
http://<yoursite.com>/wp-admin/options.php

image_default_size

Available Options:

thumbnail
medium
large
full-size

WARNING: Do not change any other setting on this page unless you know what you are doing, serious damage can be done. It’s always a good idea to perform a backup before attempting any changes to the options.php page

Info source: https://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-change-the-default-attachment-display-settings-in-wordpress-without-a-plugin/